# Does everything have to be an aggregate? Many-to-Many Link

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design

Say I have two entities
Notifications and Users.

I want to mark that a user has seen a specific notification.

This would commonly be done with a many-to-many relationship
e.g. UserNotification

Because there is no invariant around this relationship (we don't care if "all" users have seen the notification) these users shouldn't be on the notification aggregate.
On the opposite side, the users aggregate doesn't need a list of notifications on it

So that leads to say that the UserNotification (this relationship) is an aggregate of its own.
However, because we are never going to reference this thing by Id, does it really really belong as one? It seems like just adding an aggregate for storing the data.

What should I do here?

1. Just make an aggregate anyway and ignore the id?
2. Put these notifications on the user or users on notifications. (does it belong on either, and would putting it on one not add weight and cause concurrency issues?)
3. just make a crud table?
4. An aggregate without the id and keep the composite key (is that allowed?)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does a Notification have its own lifecycle? Can a Notification exist without a User to be notified?

I could imagine a Notification to simply be a Value Object that gets copied to each affected User.

Comment: Yes. Notifications are raise in the system, and they will have filters (like only show to admin users)
Then we only want to check when a users has seen a notification, so we don't show it to them again. so we currently have a many to many relationship table for user, notification to show they have seen it.
A notification can exist though without users

Comment: Thats not to say that the value object for the notification reference could be on the user, to manage this, by the notification does have its own aggregate.
My only issues with that is, is the managing of making sure the users notifications lists being populated right? and how does that effect the weight of the user. The user is a pretty base aggregate with lots of potential references/lists on it. Also does this effect concurency?

Comment: Showing them to admin users sounds like they may be a separate bounded context. Notifications can be Entities in the admin context and simple Value Objects in the receiving user’s context. And checking whether a notification had been displayed to a specific user can be done in the Notification Value Object attached to the respective user. Keep in mind: I’m not saying this would be the “correct” way to model this. But I’ve learned over time that defining proper context boundaries and (re-)shaping objects for the different contexts often made things much simpler to me.

Comment: Showing them to admins was just an example. they have filters so you can filter users. So, only admins, only standard, only users for x client, ect...
Yer I think part of my problem is that I need to just have a go and refactor later, knowing more about boundaries later maybe.

Comment: Going on the thought of adding them to the user. If i raise a notification, that events going to be picked up and stick that notification on the users that meet the criteria? Ill manage these user notification references with the events.
Sounds good, thank you

Comment: Yes. Trying to come up with a simple model that works and revisiting later sounds reasonable.

Comment: One concern I have is, when a notification is created, I'm going to have to loop through each user, check if they are meeting the filter criteria, then add it to their collection.
It doesn't seem that efficient. we have a fair amount of users. This is partially why the many-to-many was fitting, cause you could forget about that and just deal with on seen.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

have you considered modeling `User` and `Notification` as aggregates but NOT modelling the association at all?

There is a high probability of not needing to. The only usecase I can come up with is retrieving all notifcations of a user. this can be exposed in an repository interface via `getNotifications(user: User): Iterable[Notifications]` (scala syntax).

on the write side the `saveNotification(notification: Notification, users: List[User])` could save the aggregate as well as populate the n:m table.

---

EDIT: on afterthought to this - my solution would introduce a source code dependency from notifications to users (at least on the repository) and your intiuition might be right - the notification should not know about the user at all.

But there has to be at least the concept of an `Recipient` which may perfectly reside in the notification "module" or "package". maybe you are crossing bounded contexts here and the `User` entity on one side should be translated to an `Recipient` value object on the other via Anti Corruption Layer.

It's up to you and your domain to decide. In this example it would perfectly make sense that the notification package has some knowledge about a "User". otherwise - what would be notified?

Comment: We also need to keep track of which notifications a user has seen, so we don't show them to them again. Also might be helpful for analytics, idk.
You're comments regarding Recipients backs up @DennisTraub comments, which is helpful.
I do currently think that there is a notification bounded context, which I can seperate, and that has a user concept. notifications do need to know about users and some other aspects of the system.

Comment: in this case reconsider your naming. you have a `Message` that is sent to user. The `Notification` IS the user-message relation ship which allows tracking information for each individual user on per-message basis. so you may have a false idea of what a `Notification` is in this case. the problem here is that these are rather technical concepts. so yeah, if you ask the domain expert they will talk about "notifications" which you interpret actually as `Message` domain object. do you get my point?

Comment: i can see you're point of "technical concepts". These did derive from the tech side. we developed it into the system to notify certain users (a selection of users we want) of different things, be it in the system or related to their experience.
We just want to notify the user of something.
This is why I still feel the concepts of users and notifications still are named (i could be wrong, but I can't think of anything else)

Comment: Well, actually my point is: what you identified as `UserNotification` could as well be named `Notification` because it notifies a certain user about a `Message` and tracks the status of itself. what you identified as `Notification` now is actually the `Message` or something like that. A true domain export would still talk about "notifications" because to him it's the same. but these are differenct concepts. In general I would advise against an aggregate with join table name. eg `UserNotification`. its a design smell - as i said you probably don't need it or there is another aggregate hidden